# Where in the database is the Woocommerce product category count stored?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to have custom count in woocommerce categories. So categories don't show if they have products that are out of stock or are marked as do not display on website.

I can't seem to change the value that displays on the categories page.

I have tried: 
Changing the value in the count column of wp_term_taxonomy table. 
Changing the value in the wp_termmeta of metakey product_count_product_tag

With both of these changes the count displayed doesn't seem to change.

I can't seem to find anywhere the value might be being cached.
Nor can I find any hooks that might alter the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found at least a partial answer to my question.

The count is stored in the term_taxonomy table but when it is displaying the subcategories it shows all of them

I found a hook that allows you to change the args so you can hide empty since by default hide empty = false and pad_count = 1 so you need to set hide_empty to true and set pad_count = 0 (otherwise it adds one to the count and none of them are 0)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_args','hide_subcategories_with_no_products', 10, 1 ); 

function hide_subcategories_with_no_products( $args ) {
    $args['hide_empty'] = 1;
    $args['hierarchical'] = true;
    $args['pad_counts'] = 0;    
    return $args; 
}
```

NOTE:  for me the woocommerce_product_subcategories_hide_empty HOOK did not work.  I think this may be because either it is using count(*) instead of the count column or the pad_count being set to 1